# Building Dropdown Selection from SQL Statement using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a website where you can get information about some content in the database using some parameters you can set before. 
By now the page loads the SQL Statement (to populate the dropdown menu for selection) from a file, executes it and adds HTML code as shown below:

```
while($rec = $connection->FetchRow($result))
{                           
    $selected = (in_array($rec[0], $arr) OR $bSelFirst == TRUE) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    $sResult = htmlentities($rec[0], ENT_QUOTES, "iso8859-1" );
    $sMatchcode = htmlentities($rec[1], ENT_QUOTES, "iso8859-1" );

    $tmprslt .= '  <option value="'.$sResult.'" '.$selected.'>  '.$sResult.';'.$sMatchcode.'</option>';                 
    $bSelFirst = false;
}
```

The problem with this code is, on large results the page takes ages to build and the dropdown menu is almost unusable because it's so slow, sometimes the tab even crashes.

My question now is, how would I load in these information dynamically? Like, you type something into the input field and it only loads or displays relevant answers (e.g. I type "Ap" then it shows me all results that contain "Ap" (case sensitive)).

Comment: so what you want is something like autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, that sounds suitable, but I think I will need another component to have it loading dynamically and not display everything at once, don't I?

Comment: here's an example of what you want.. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
when the page loads you need to run a jquery.ajax that retrieves data from  the database...  put it on an array and substitute the `availableTags` you see on the example... =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

The page loads, user sees a select/text box, types something in, you filter results in the back end and return them as JSON.

Alternatively, you could write the JS yourself (even so, I strongly suggest you use a library such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)).

Answer (score 3):

If [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) works for you, how about you use a PHP code in the server to fetch and send the data in `JSON` format? Then you can easily use the response from the page to display in the dropdown using jQuery, as thus:

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$q=$_REQUEST["q"]; 
$sql="something";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$json=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  array_push($json, $row['varName']);
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#awesome" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getdata.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
```